# How to send JSON object as JSON String with Postman?

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I want to send a JSON request but problem is I need to send my userPropertiesAsJsonString field as JSON string.

How can I send userPropertiesAsJsonString as JSON string?

```
{
    "User" : {
        "userId" : "11111",
        "userPropertiesAsJsonString" : ?
    }
}
```

userPropertiesAsJsonString is;

```
{
    "properties" : {
        "propertyName" : "test",
        "propertyDesc" : "desc"
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with pasting what you posted here in Postman? Should work if I'm not mistaken. Just make sure the quotes are escaped with `\"` instead of just `"`

Comment: If this is in JavaScript, can’t you just do `JSON.stringify(userPropertiesAsJsonString)` there?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this :

```
{
    "User" : {
        "userId" : "11111",
        "userPropertiesAsJsonString" : "{\"properties\" : {\"propertyName\" : \"test\",\"propertyDesc\" : \"desc\"}}"
    }
}
```

Comment: This has to be in one line, and it is quite a crappy solution. I wish we could use `''` or (back ticks)

Answer (score 25):

[Jason Mullings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4540509/jason-mullings)' answer did not work for me, but it was an excellent base that allowed me to come up with a solution to a problem very similar to yours.

In the Pre-request Script tab,

```
const userPropertiesAsJsonString = {
    "properties" : {
        "propertyName" : "test",
        "propertyDesc" : "desc"
    }
}

pm.environment.set(
    'userPropertiesAsJsonString',
    JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(userPropertiesAsJsonString))
);
```

Then, in the Body tab,

```
{
    "User" : {
        "userId" : "11111",
        "userPropertiesAsJsonString" : {{userPropertiesAsJsonString}}
    }
}
```

Stringifying the `userPropertiesAsJsonString` variable twice will allow you to escape the JSON string (solution obtained from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48577224); refer to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/d6e10171d44a59bb5664617c64ff2763) for a more detailed explanation) which will then allow you to obtain a request body that looks like the one in the answer provided by [sanatsathyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9198744/sanatsathyan).

Comment: Using JSON.stringify twice is brilliant, it is the only solution that worked for me in Postman, thank you.

Comment: @sabriele Happy to have been of some help ;-)

Answer (score 8):

pre-request script:

```
let query = {}

pm.environment.set('query', JSON.stringify(query));
```

body:

```
{{query}}
```

Comment: Nested JSON needs to be escaped, so doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

As JSON means JavaScript Object Notation, so you can just copy the userPropertiesAsJsonString into the original JSON:

```
{
    "User" : {
        "userId" : "11111",
        "userPropertiesAsJsonString" : {
            "properties" : {
                "propertyName" : "test",
                "propertyDesc" : "desc"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Copy and paste this JSON into the Postman request body (raw formatted) and set the header "Content-Type: application/json".

If you have to do more fancy stuff before the request you can execute a pre-request script in Postman: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/pre_request_scripts

For more about JSON see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Comment: This is what i would go for, just use the original JSON and not a string - As it's using Postman to `POST` the request payload, `JSON.stringify()` won't work as the app will fail the validation as it checking that the schema is valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to other answers but:

```
pm.variables.set('myJsonAsEscapedString',JSON.stringify(`{"user_id": 1, "name": "Jhon"}`))
```

That way you can use it without escaping explicitly.