# Spotify Web API Error 400 "Missing Tracks" when removing item from a playlist - Pizzly

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch-api, spotify

I'm trying to remove a song from an authenticated Spotify user's playlist and for some reason, I get `Error 400 Missing Tracks`, even though I know the song is there and the playlist is correct

I am using [Pizzly from Bearer](https://github.com/Bearer/Pizzly) to handle the API request

Any idea what could be causing this issue? This is the link to [Spotify's API Documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/remove-tracks-playlist/)

This is an example output of `JSON.stringify(body)`

`{"tracks":[{"uri":"spotify:track:2fTdRdN73RgIgcUZN33dvt"}]}`

```js
   async removeSongsFromPlaylist(context, payload) {
        var tracks = payload[0]
        var playlistID = payload[1] || context.getters.user.favorites_playlist.id
        var authID = context.getters.spotifyAuthID
        var endpoint = `/playlists/${playlistID}/tracks`

        var uris = tracks.map(track => { return {uri: track.uri}})
        var body = {"tracks": uris}
        console.log(`URIS:`)
        console.log(body);
        console.log(`playlist: ${playlistID}`);
        return pizzly.integration("spotify").auth(authID).delete(endpoint, {
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(responseJSON => {
                console.log("song successfully deleted")
                console.log(responseJSON)
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))
        

    },
```

**Update:** I did make some progress with a very hacky solution

I took [Spotify's cURL example](https://developer.spotify.com/console/delete-playlist-tracks/?playlist_id=3cEYpjA9oz9GiPac4AsH4n&body=%7B%22tracks%22%3A%5B%7B%22uri%22%3A%22spotify%3Atrack%3A7MDKvOzNgAJ3KMCtaP2UOa%22%7D%5D%7D), converted it to fetch with this [link](https://kigiri.github.io/fetch/) and put that inside my function as so:

```js
        fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/${playlistID}/tracks`, {
            body: "{\"tracks\":[{\"uri\":\"" + tracks[0].uri + "\"}]}",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                Authorization: "Bearer ~accessTokenHiddenForPrivacy~",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            method: "DELETE"
        })     
        .then(response => response.json())
```

Fortunately it worked! The problem is that I tried copy and pasting the `body` from below into the code above and it still shows "Missing Tracks". I cannot keep this code below without another way of getting the user's access token- which is currently handled by pizzly and the auth id.

Comment: Might the error message mean that Spotify isn't receiving the `tracks` parameter in the expected way? Perhaps you could examine the output of `JSON.stringify(body)`, and share it with us you don't see a problem (and you agree it might help).

Comment: Did not think of this! Happy to - `{"tracks":[{"uri":"spotify:track:2fTdRdN73RgIgcUZN33dvt"}]}
`

Comment: Looks well-formed to me!

Comment: Yes! And actually I made some progress from your comment, however - it will not suffice! But it did disprove that theory. Am updating the main post with info.

Comment: Basically I produced a hacky solution but the issue is I use pizzly to store the user's access token, which is currently hard-coded.

Comment: Huh, If Spotify wants all those escaped quotes, would invoking `stringify` twice do the trick? (Suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48577224/7711863).)

Comment: I gave it a shot to no avail. Given that I tried to copy and paste the `fetch` body into the `pizzly` body and it failed makes me think the offender is not in the body param. But i dont know where the issue would be otherwise