# receiving newline inside a json object

Tags: php, ajax, json, newline

i am trying to bring a set of texts from a PostgreSQL database (field type is text) with ajax into my webpage. The problem i encouter is the newline, it works great when there is no newlines into the text in database, but when i use new lines in the text inside database, the json doesnt give me the data it stored.

```
function selectCalendarEvents(user_id, event_datestart, event_datestop, callback) {
    var request;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            if(request.responseText.substr(0, 6) == "error ")
                alert(errorName[request.responseText.substr(6)]);
            else {
                jsonCalendarEvents = $.parseJSON(request.responseText);
                selectEvents(user_id, event_datestart, event_datestop, callback);
            }
        }
    }
    request.open("GET", "php/calendar.php?action=selectCalendarEvents&user_id=" + user_id + "&event_datestart=" + event_datestart + "&event_datestop=" + event_datestop, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
    request.send();
}
```

this is my javascript function which requests the data set

```
if($action == "selectCalendarEvents") {
        $user_id = $_GET["user_id"];
        $event_datestart = "'" . $_GET["event_datestart"] . "'";
        $event_datestop = "'" . $_GET["event_datestop"] . "'";

        require_once("connect.php");
        $query = "SELECT event_id, event_name, event_datestart, event_datestop, event_timestart, event_timestop, calendar_events.calendar_group, calendar_color, event_info FROM calendar_events LEFT JOIN calendar_calendars ON calendar_events.calendar_group = calendar_calendars.calendar_group WHERE user_id = " . $user_id . " AND calendar_show = true AND event_datestart <= ". $event_datestop . " AND event_datestop >= " . $event_datestart;
        $result = pg_query($connect, $query);
        if(!$result)
            die("error 1"); // query error

        $comma = '';
        $json = '{"events":[';
        while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
            $json .= $comma . '{';
            $json .= '"event_id":"' . $row[0] . '",';
            $json .= '"event_name":"' . $row[1] . '",';
            $json .= '"event_datestart":"' . $row[2] . '",';
            $json .= '"event_datestop":"' . $row[3] . '",';
            $json .= '"event_timestart":"' . $row[4] . '",';
            $json .= '"event_timestop":"' . $row[5] . '",';
            $json .= '"calendar_group":"' . $row[6] . '",';
            $json .= '"calendar_color":"' . $row[7] . '",';
            $json .= '"event_info":"' . $row[8] . '"';
            $json .= '}';
            $comma = ',';
        }
        $json .= ']}';

        echo $json;
    }
```

this is my php which returns the dataset. If row[8] aka event_info stores text with newlines in it .. when i try to populate my calendar with the events, it seems the json doesnt store any data in it or smt like that.

Comment: Escape the newlines in javascript before you parseJSON it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253367/how-to-escape-a-json-string-containing-newline-characters-using-javascript

Comment: You can also read an tutorial about replacing json [line break to html line break](http://www.lampcoder.com/how-to-parse-line-breaks-using-jquery-post-method-and-json/)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that i should replace `\r\n` with `<br/>` and it will work. im using like this `replace(/\r\n/g, "<br/>")` when i give the response string to json

```
jsonCalendarEvents = $.parseJSON(request.responseText.replace(/\r\n/g, "<br/>"));
```