# freeze while waiting for www-class call

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I have problems when I receive certain strings via the www class from a php file. At the php end, I echo a string and some strings freeze the Unity script that was making the WWW call (Unity 4.6.0). If I call the php file from the browser (direct url address) then it never gives any problems. The strings are always echoed fine.

The strings that I want to echo are the result of json_encode, but that shouldn’t matter. In my debugging mode, I have created a string that looks like the json_encoded string. Then I have tried different versions of the string, to see which ones freeze the calling app. So the php code ends like this:

```
$matches = 'one string’;
echo $matches;
```

See below the different strings I tried ($matches).
DOES NOT WORK = this string freezes the calling app;
WORKS = with this string the AJAX call is completed successfully, the app receives the data and moves on

```
$matches = '[{"Start":"2015-02-02 08:00:00","Duration":"15","nSituations":1}]'; // DOES NOT WORK
$matches = '[{"Start":"2015-02-02 08:00:00","Duration":"15"}]'; // WORKS
$matches = '[{"Start":"2015-02-02 08:00:00","nSituations":1}]'; // WORKS
$matches = '[{"Duration":"15","nSituations":1}]'; // WORKS
$matches = '[{"Start":"A","Duration":"15","nSituations":1}]'; // WORKS
$matches = '[{"Start":"2015-02-02 08:00:00","Duration":"15","nSituations":"1"}]'; // DOES NOT WORK (notice nSituations as STRING)
$matches = '[{"Start":"2015-02-02","Duration":"15","nSituations":"1"}]'; // DOES NOT WORK
$matches = '[{"Start":"08:00:00","Duration":"15","nSituations":"1"}]'; // DOES NOT WORK
$matches = '[{"Start":"08:00:00","Duration":"15","nSituations":1}]'; // DOES NOT WORK (nSituations back as INT)
$matches = '[{"Start":"2015-02-02 08:00:00"}]'; // WORKS
```

I can’t see any pattern. Does anyone know what is going on here?
There’s [this older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890464/php-ajax-json-json-echo-from-php-freezes-script), but it does not quite help me, I don’t think.

Comment: You need to see where the issue is - monitor the http requests with something like wireshark, then you can see if the issue is the server not responding, or the app failing to deal with the response.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the input. I don't know about wireshark but I could check it out. When I call the php file from the browser it works fine with all strings. Can the fact that it's being called via AJAX make the php file to fail?

Comment: No, probably not, unless you are sending some data for php to process -  if you are just echoing a string, then chances are the server is always sending a responce, and the client is failing to process it in certain instances. I am not familiar with unity so do not know what debugging options are available, but you need to walk through the javascript that performs the ajax and see where it fails

Comment: No, I'm not sending any data. Just echoing a string (in my debugging mode). And it still fails, so the problem should be at the receiving end. I'll edit the question to make this clear. Thanks for the help

Comment: Please sent unity3d code too. Maybe you forgot calling [StartCoroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)