# Is it possible to jsonify string within mysql query?

Tags: mysql, json

I need to get the values from a table in json format , directly using mysql query (no post processing in php etc at application level). Most of the field of the table are integer and its not hard to build a json string for the records , but one column is a `text` type and my contain all the garbage .

Is is possible to `stringify` that text type column data to build a valid json string ?

query:

```
 select concat('var sp_json= [',
    group_concat(
      '{"sp_no":',sp_no,',
        "sp_group_no":',sp_group_no,',
        "sp_weight":',sp_weight,',
        "dg_list":[',dg_list,'],
        "comments":\'',coalesce(comments,''),'\'}'
    order by sp_group_no
    ),
   ']') as sp_json

  from sp_dg where  pm_id=1 group by pm_id
```

This outputs a javascript json objects etc

```
  var sp_json=[{},,,]
```

I need way to stringify `comments` using a built-in mysql function if there is one. Please share your thoughts .

Comment: There is no JSON stringify function in mySQL as far as I know.

Comment: @Pekka웃 thanks, what do you suggest ?

Comment: Using server side post processing would be the most strightforward way. This *may* be possible in pure MySQL but it's going to be a gigantic pain if you want it able to deal with newlines, all kinds of quotes, etc. as you indicate in the comment below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [MySQL's String `REPLACE` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) with the concepts found in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204218/1481489).

E.g. (SQL):

```
REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        coalesce(comments,''),'\\','\\\\'
    ),'"','\\"'
)
```

Comment: thanks, do you think it will handle all the anti-json characters ? new lines, quotes (single , double ) etc ..

Comment: @sakhunzai those characters you speak of are mentioned in the answer I have linked to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253367/how-to-escape-a-json-string-containing-newline-characters-using-javascript/9204218#9204218). You'll need to nest several `REPLACE` functions to account for all characters (8 in total).

Comment: yes that is reasonable , but I have to write lots of json functions or a bulky large one. Giving you benefit of doubt I ll accept this answer as :)