# javascript does not pass single quote to php server side correctly

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, http, codemirror

I stored in javascript variable that

```
echo '';
```

as a string and http call the variable to transfer it into php with

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$objData = json_decode($data);
```

However, the result will be always as

```
echo '
```

and if there is

```
echo '';
echo '';
```

then result will be

```
 echo '; 
 echo ';
```

I wonder how to resolve this situation with some kind of javascript build in function that can somehow maybe, see all the ' and make sure none them will not disappear.

Are there other characters that may encounter similar situation?

CONDITION: the string is stored in js first, I can not take the string without an http call.

I use **CodeMirror** and **Angular**

I tried I tried `var myEscapedJSONString = myJSONString.replace(/'/g, " ' ")`, but its just happened that result becomes`"echo "`instead....

Thanks

Comment: escape like echo \' \' or create an object in js and send it as json

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253367/how-to-escape-a-json-string-containing-newline-characters-using-javascript).

Comment: @John, I updated the last sentence of the question, but what suggested seems not working very well....

Comment: I'm confused. You're calling `json_decode()` but `echo '';` isn't JSON.

Comment: @VoteyDisciple Ah! I see, but echo'' is stored as string value of an object inside a JSON though!

Comment: Can you give an example of the JSON?

Comment: @Chen is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bvVbE/1/) what you're looking for?

Comment: @John, I typed echo ('1'); into the demo, but get 
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function error