# Json.Parse escape newline characters

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, json, escaping

I have a page where I am trying to parse following json string using JSON.parse

```
'[{"Name":"Eggs","Complete":false,"Notes":"Notes here\n"},{"Name":"Sugar","Complete":false,"Notes":null}]'
```

But following code gives error `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token"`

```
var groceriesJson = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Then I came to know that its because of `\n` in json string. So I did try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253367/how-to-escape-a-json-string-containing-newline-characters-using-javascript). But no luck. Still same error `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token"`

```
function escapeSpecialChars(jsonString) {

        return jsonString.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n")
              .replace(/\\'/g, "\\'")
              .replace(/\\"/g, '\\"')
              .replace(/\\&/g, "\\&")
              .replace(/\\r/g, "\\r")
              .replace(/\\t/g, "\\t")
              .replace(/\\b/g, "\\b")
              .replace(/\\f/g, "\\f");

      }

 var groceriesJson = JSON.parse(escapeSpecialChars(jsonString));
```

Any ideas? Thanks

**---UPDATE----**

I am not creating this string manually, I have c# codes that creates json string from c# objects

```
 var jss = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
 var groceries = jss.Serialize(Model);
```

then in javascript codes I have

```
var jsonString = '@Html.Raw(groceries)'
 var groceriesJson = JSON.parse(escapeSpecialChars(jsonString));
```

Comment: Why are you trying to embed JSON as a string literal in your JavaScript? Just use it as an array literal and skip the manual parsing step.

Comment: That works.I'll mark it as answer if you can post answer. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You should just escape the `\` as in `\\n`, your JSON becoming :

```
'[{"Name":"Eggs","Complete":false,"Notes":"Notes here\\n"},{"Name":"Sugar","Complete":false,"Notes":null}]';
```

If you cannot have access to the JSON, then your function should be :

```
function escapeSpecialChars(jsonString) {

    return jsonString.replace(/\n/g, "\\n")
        .replace(/\r/g, "\\r")
        .replace(/\t/g, "\\t")
        .replace(/\f/g, "\\f");

}

 var groceriesJson = JSON.parse(escapeSpecialChars(jsonString));
```

Comment: I am not creating json string manually. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

As @Quentin suggests you can skip storing the value inside the literal and simply do something like this:

```
var jsonObject = @Html.Raw(groceries);
```