# Passing a variable inside json string

Tags: javascript, json

I have a simple var with some strings that I convert to a json object. I would like to have an input field for the persons name and then add the text.

Currently I have this

```
var text = '{"students":[' +
'{"firstName": "Brendan","lastName":"Skousen" },' +
'{"firstName":"Scooby","lastName":"Doo" },' +
'{"firstName":"Your","lastName":"Mom" }]}';
```

and I have a var for my input

```
var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
```

So I would like to have the var text work like this:

```
var text = '{"students":[' +
'{"firstName": first,"lastName":"Skousen" },' +
'{"firstName": first,"lastName":"Norman" },' +
'{"firstName": first,"lastName":"Coatney" }]}';
```

You can see the full code at: http://codepen.io/bskousen/pen/xbPLew

Comment: Use `JSON.parse`, change it, `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = '{"students":[' +
'{"firstName": ' + escape(first) + ',"lastName":"Skousen" },' +
'{"firstName": ' + escape(first) + ',"lastName":"Norman" },' +
'{"firstName": ' + escape(first) + ',"lastName":"Coatney" }]}';
```

Using `escape` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204218/4538344).

Answer (score -1):

To make it work the way you use it in your example you would have to use a [template engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+string+template+engine&oq=javascript+string+template+engine&aqs=chrome..69i57.5748j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8) and add some extra characters around the variable depending on the engine you went with. I think concatenation would be easiest for your case

```
var text = '{"students":[' +
'{"firstName": ' + first + ',"lastName":"Skousen" },' +
'{"firstName": ' + first + ',"lastName":"Norman" },' +
'{"firstName": ' + first + ',"lastName":"Coatney" }]}';
```