# unescape special characters in ajax response data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have an ajax request with dataType: 'json'

The json received (being well formed) contains strings with newlines escaped

`i.e '{ "a"  :  "x\\r\\nx" }'`

unfortunately the resultant data object in the ajax done function now also contains the newline in that form `("\\r\\n")`

I want all string fields in the ajax result data object to be unescaped so that in this case I will get

`data = { a:"xNEWLINEx" }`

Is there a *general* way to do this ? assume data may have nested arrays and dictionaries each containing strings which can have newlines (or other escaped special characters)

Comment: Why doesn’t the client just send `{"a":"x\r\nx"}` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on the response from yangguang, here is a complete solution:

```
    // 'unescape' all special characters in all strings in an object that was created from JSON (ie, ajax reply) 
    function jUnescape(obj) {
       var j = JSON.stringify(obj);
       ['b', 'f', 'n', 'r', 't', 'u'].forEach(function(c) {
          j=j.split('\\\\' + c).join('\\' + c);
       });
       j = j.split('\\\\\\"').join('\\"');
       j = j.split('\\\\\\\\').join('\\\\');
       return JSON.parse(j);
    }
```

see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f6bh9pbu/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace`:

```
data.a = data.a.replace('\\', '\');
```

You can also use `unescape`(Warning: **Deprecated**):

```
data.a = unescape(data.a);
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape

For Objects:

```
for (var key in data) {
    data[key] = unescape(data[key]);
}
```

Comment: I am asking for a general solution not relying on knowing the structure of data. Suppose data contains many string fields in nested arrays and dictionaries and any such string may contain newlines

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
var data = { a: "x\\r\\nx" };
data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log('data', data);
//Object {a: "x\r\nx"}
```

for more "\", you can try:

```
var data = { a: "x\\\\r\\\\nx" };
data = JSON.stringify(data);
data = data.replace(/\\+r\\+n/g,'\\\\r\\\\n');
data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log('data', data);
//Object {a: "x\r\nx"}
```

Comment: This still ends up with the slashes in the string. What I want is the special chars there.

I can do data = data.replace(/\\+r\\+n/g,'\\r\\n');

this works ! but there is one things that I'm not sure about, after such a replace the string we end up with is no longer a valid json - since we  removed the escapes it now contains special chars  ... we then run JSON.parse on what is an illegal json string .. I think that is not compliant. Still seems to work (at least in chrome)

Comment: @kofifus yes, to get *{a: "x↵x"}* (which is different with *{ a:"x\r\nx" }*, described in your question), you need do *.replace(/\\+r\\+n/g,'\\r\\n')*. but it still a valid json. you can use *JSON.stringify({"a":"x↵x"})* to test.