# Use Text from Textarea in JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, fpdf

Now I googled a bit and could not find anything that may helps me so I decided to ask you.

I have a script that collects Data from a form. Source is not needed.

There is also a `<textarea id="sample"></textarea>` where some content gets written in. In my jQuery is use following Line:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cData = {};
    var url = 'http://www.sample.xy/samplefolder/index.php?cData=';

    $('#submit_btn').on('click', function(){

        //here are some more fields
        //...

        cData.text = $('#sample').val();
    }

    var bCode = btoa('{"field_one":"' + cData.field_one + '", "text":"' + cData.text + '"}');
    //sending the data...
    window.open(url + bCode, '_blank');
});
```

Actually this all works fine. But on the PHP side I run into json problems.

`btoa`  transforms my content into a base64 string. My PHP source looks like

```
$data   =  base64_decode( $_GET['cData'] ) ;
```

What brings me the expacted string

```
{"field_one":"i am field one","text":"I am a text over
multiple rows

and this makes me
not valid for json"}
```

As you may noticed in the content of `text`, multirow causes the json validate of `json_decode( ... )` to fail.

**So my question is, how can I get the multi row valid for json without losing the linebreaks?** Because I need them as they are. Because I want to use the content to create a PDF file with FPDF. So filling in `<br />` doesn't really helps.

I tried `json_encode` before `json_decode` what just retuned my a `null` :/

Comment: JSON does not allow line-breaks, you need to replace all the line breaks into `\n`

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253367/how-to-escape-a-json-string-containing-newline-characters-using-javascript

Comment: but textarea uses `\n` too... or how can I catch the textarea linebreaks ?

Comment: @Typoheads, hmm i try this... i will tell you if i was successful