# How to correctly handle an Unterminated string exception?

Tags: javascript, java, json, escaping

I'm using the [JSON.org java library](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) to tinker with.

At the moment I'm encountering an error because of `\n` characters:

```
try{
            String s = "{\"property:\":\"line1\n,line2\"}";
            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(s);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
```

results in:

```
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at 20 [character 0 line 2]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextString(JSONTokener.java:261)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:361)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:218)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:325)
```

After doing a quick search I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253367/how-to-escape-a-json-string-containing-newline-characters-using-javascript)
which points to my string having to be escaped like so:

```
String s = "{\"property:\":\"line1\\n,line2\"}";
```

I would no longer see the exception and could do a string replace for `"\n"` with `'\n'`, but I'm just wondering:

**is the recommended way of dealing with new lines in a JSON string in java ?**

Comment: What has this to do with JavaScript?

Comment: The JSON part mostly. I didn't mention in my question that I would normally receive this string from Javascript (websocket), where my main java code would be a basic Websocket Server. I didn't want to overcomplicate things, since this revolves mostly around JSON parsing in java

Comment: Note that `obj.get("property:")` would return a properly decoded `String` value, ie. one where the `\n` in JSON becomes a newline character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in [the JSON specification](http://json.org/), JSON does not allow real line breaks in strings, so you always need to escape newline characters with `\n`. This is not a special Java thing. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json).