# Displaying special characters, HTML entities, unicode as is in rendered HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, unicode

I am receiving an annotated `json` from the backend, which i need to display in UI.

The `json` contains strings tagged according to position and length in the content.

It may contain characters like `\t \n` or extra `whitespaces`, also `html entities, unicode` etc. When I try to display it in HTML, this information is lost, `html entities` are converted to respective values, `whitespaces` are reduced to single, `unicode` is converted to corresponding character.

I want to display the content as is, because i need to highlight the annotations and I am allowing the user to tag things as well, and if he tags them in the displayed HTML, the position and length would be different from the original json.

**Example:**

json:

```
{
"content": " \tHi there &nbsp how are you?"
}
```

This is displayed as `"Hi there"`, and so if i want to highlight `'how'`, which is tagged at position 17, in the UI i would get it at position 10 or 11.

Also if a user wants to tag `'are'`, it would get tagged at 14, while the server would expect it to be tagged at 21.

**EDIT:**

this is what i have till now:

**1)** all html entities are converted as:

`&gt; --> &amp;gt` so that they get displayed as `&gt;` in the rendered HTML and not `>`

**2)** \t, \r , \n are converted as:

`\t --> \\t` , so that it gets displayed as `\t`

**3)** i can also recognize unicode characters and convert them:

`\u --> \\u` , so that they get displayed as it is

but there are some other issues like, extra whitespaces, foreign characters, patterns like \x etc. i don't think i have a comprehensive list of everything, and sooner or later it might break.

Comment: I think it helps you: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253367/how-to-escape-a-json-string-containing-newline-characters-using-javascript).

Answer (score 2):

That’s exactly what [`jsesc`](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jsesc) does. From the README:

> *jsesc* is a JavaScript library for [escaping JavaScript strings](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes) while generating the shortest possible valid ASCII-only output. [Here’s an online demo.](https://mothereff.in/js-escapes)

Use it as follows:

```
var data = { "content": " \tHi there &nbsp how are you?"};
var escaped = jsesc(data.content);
// → ' \\tHi there &nbsp how are you?'
```

There are many options to customize the output. See the documentation for more details.

To display the jsesc output in HTML, don’t set it to an element’s `.innerHTML` but rather use `.textContent`.

Comment: Haven't looked into it yet, but another issue is that I have to highlight some words and that would require HTML, and I think textContent would not be able to display that

Comment: Take a look to jsesc, like @Mathias has said, it does that you need.

Comment: @elchininet, actually this library would escape things and convert them to unicode, like if a non printable character or a foreign language word would be converted to unicode, which would again mess up with my position and offset

Comment: The library has some options, if you no treat the output as a javascript string body, the library escapes all "\" and "&" characters. Test with an example string that you receive from backend.

Comment: yeah, but did you see how the foreign characters were converted to unicode...also, i can't set it as textContent because i need to have some html as well

Comment: You are right, i tested with Spanish characters and saw the result :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this little function, add regular expressions depending on the received characters:

```
function html(str){
    return str.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/\t/g, "\\t").replace(/\n/g, "\\n").replace(/\r/g, "\\r");
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/asL1cu1s/)

Comment: This is what I am presently doing to escape/show HTML entities, but there are other things like Unicode and \t etc, and I don't know all the possibilities

Comment: The unicode characters are represented by "\uXXXXX", add "\u" to the regular expressions. In my solutions I added "\t", "\n" and "\r" already, there is no much more possibilities.

Comment: Could you provide me with an example data to see all situations, I'm sure that it could be accomplished with regular expressions replacements (The extra white spaces could be accomplished with regular expressions too)

Comment: the input is a set of a million documents, each sourced from diverse sources, from the web as well as docs, pdfs and what not. Initially i decided to add functions as and when i encountered a new issue, but that's actually taking a lot of effort and stalling the development.

Comment: Ok I understand that. But with regexps you could match many patterns, and I think that could be solved. For example, with the single replacement of "&" for "&amp;" you manage &lt; &gt; &amp; &excl; &quest; etc , with the replacement of escaped "%u" for "\\u" you solved all unicode characters, the rest will be octal characters, new lines, returns, tabs that formed with "\" at the beginning. If you provide more examples of data maybe we could arrive to a good solution, I only trying to help you to find a solution. Forgive me for my very bad english.

Comment: ya got your point, but i asked this question to do away with this task of finding more examples. if i find them, i would write a regex or a function to escape them correctly. the issue is, i would not need to think about writing the functions/regex, if there was an easier way to handle everything as is