# Assigning string value in <script> tag with "\n" is getting an error

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to assign a string value to a javascript variable as below:

```
<script>

var iAmDone = 'asdasdaGRTPXqe1RWA8jikLwJSDc0lSNWCGA8NPioRhXlgxbQuTuxS6kkt3cA\nkDKp9/8zvA==';

</script>
```

This assignment is breaking the assignment from '\n' and thereby the value in iAmDone is not getting assigned. When I look into the console, it shows:

```
var iAmDone = 'asdasdaGRTPXqe1RWA8jikLwJSDc0lSNWCGA8NPioRhXlgxbQuTuxS6kkt3cA
kDKp9/8zvA==';  **X error**
```

What can I do to make the browser understand the `\n` is not a newline but part of a string?

** Just to add - The value is an encoded string and changing the same would be the last thing in my mind **

Comment: Escape it! `var iAmDone = 'asdasdaGRTPXqe1RWA8jikLwJSDc0lSNWCGA8NPioRhXlgxbQuTuxS6kkt3cA\\nkDKp9/8zvA==';`

Comment: This value is an encrypted value coming from the backend services. If I put an extra \ it might not get decrypted to the same value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253367/how-to-escape-a-json-string-containing-newline-characters-using-javascript

Comment: How exactly does the string end up in your source code? You probably need to write some code to escape characters that have special meaning in HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

`\n` means new line, so string '12\n34' will be logged as:

```
'12
34'
```

To remedy this, you need to "escape" the string.  For your specific case, you can add an additional `\`, IE `'12\n34'` -> `'12\\n34'`.

A more scaleable option is to use the `JSON.stringify` function:

```js
const s = `12\n34`;
console.log('s: ', s);

const stringified = JSON.stringify(s);
console.log('stringified: ', stringified);
```

`JSON.parse` will convert the stringified result back to normal.