# How should a JSON string with quotes inside can be parsed with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string

```
var str = '{"Language":"en","Type":"General","Text":""Mela" means "apple" in Italian"}';
```

Now `JSON.parse(str)` throws this error

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token M in JSON at position 43`

Now replacing quotes escapes whole string and parsed JSON is not usable anymore

`str = str.replace(/\\([\s\S])|(")/g,"\\$1$2");`

`"{\"Language\":\"en\",\"Type\":\"General\",\"Text\":\"\"Mela\" means \"apple\" in Italian\"}"`

Other solutions like below do not seem to be working in this scenario

[How to escape a JSON string containing newline characters using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253367/how-to-escape-a-json-string-containing-newline-characters-using-javascript)

Comment: Escape them like `\\\"`

Comment: Hi Federico Sir, that can be done but there can be some function/solution for this in javascript that is not in my knowledge.

Comment: You should not have to do that. Where do you get the string from? Fix the cause, not the symptoms.

Comment: Where are you getting this JSON from?

Comment: Hi chŝdk sir, It is received in ajax response fetched through php and mysql. This data I downloaded from hotelsPro it provides hotel details with api.

Comment: @VishvendraSingh Do you get it in this format from "hotelsPro"?

Comment: @chŝdk sorry, this data is from roomxml and I converted it from xml to json. This is not hotelspro data. Its my fault, I mixed it all. Damn I should have changed quotes there only. Thanks chŝdk.

Comment: Ah, Okay, so you can fix it all and escape the double quotes in XML, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a backslash before each double quote within your string as:

```js
const str = '{"Language":"en","Type":"General","Text": "\\"Mela\\" means \\"apple\\" in Italian"}';

const obj = JSON.parse(str)
console.log(obj.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

In JSON you don't escape double quotes of the property name or the begging of the property value, just escape what's inside property value:

```
{\"Text\":\"\"Mela\" means ....
```

It should be like this:

```
{"Text":"\"Mela\" means ....
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with multiple replacements:

```
var str = '{"Language":"en","Type":"General","Text":""Mela" means "apple" in Italian"}';
str = str.replace(/"/,"'"); //Replace all " with '

str = str.replace(/{'/,'{"') //Restore " to start of JSON
str = str.replace(/','/,'","'); //Restore " around JSON , separators
str = str.replace(/':'/,'":"'); //Restore " around JSON : separators
str = str.replace(/'}/,'"}'); //Restore " to end of JSON
str = str.replace(/'/,'\"'); //All remaining ' must be inside of data, so replace with properly escaped \"

console.log(str);
```

EDIT: A problem with this solution is that is will also replace original ' characters with " inside the text.