# Escape json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, escaping

Need to escape the following json

```
{
    "xx": 'a',
    "yy": "bb"
}
```

into the following structure in javascript

```
{\r\n\t\"xx\": 'a',\r\n\t\"yy\": \"bb\"\r\n}
```

I have tried the code suggestion from this link, [How to escape a JSON string containing newline characters using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253367/how-to-escape-a-json-string-containing-newline-characters-using-javascript)

```
var request = {
  "xx": "aaa",
  "yy": "bb"
}
var myJSONString = JSON.stringify(request);
var myEscapedJSONString = myJSONString.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n").replace(/\\'/g, "\\'").replace(/\\"/g, '\\"').replace(/\\&/g, "\\&").replace(/\\r/g, "\\r").replace(/\\t/g, "\\t").replace(/\\b/g, "\\b").replace(/\\f/g, "\\f");
```

but not worked, please help.

Code has to escape like the following

- Backspace is replaced with \b
- Form feed is replaced with \f
- Newline is replaced with \n
- Carriage return is replaced with \r
- Tab is replaced with \t
- Double quote is replaced with \"
- Backslash is replaced with \

Comment: Where is your attempted code?

Comment: Can you tell the reason you would want this ? May be there is a better way to achieve that. Serializing it like so, will cause issues while parsing.

Comment: I have tried this in my code, var myJSONString = JSON.stringify(request);
        var myEscapedJSONString = myJSONString.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n").replace(/\\'/g, "\\'").replace(/\\"/g, '\\"').replace(/\\&/g, "\\&").replace(/\\r/g, "\\r").replace(/\\t/g, "\\t").replace(/\\b/g, "\\b").replace(/\\f/g, "\\f"); request will contain the above given json structure {
  "xx": "aaa",
  "yy": "bb"
}

Comment: @RajeshKumar I am seconding what Dhananjai said. There is probably a better solution to your problem, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Marie - Need to send escaped json to API service as request

Comment: @RajeshKumar Why do you think it needs to be escaped? And is it a service under your control? It doesn't really make sense to require it be escaped since they would have to remove the escapes to parse it.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure why you want to do this, but stringify does exactly this, no regex or anything fancy,..  just stirngify your JSON string.

I've also sliced off the quotes..

```js
var request = {
  "xx": "aaa",
  "yy": "bb"
}
var myJSONString = JSON.stringify(request, null, 2);
var myEscapedJSONString = JSON.stringify(myJSONString).slice(1, -1);

console.log(myEscapedJSONString);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, please check the updated question for better understanding of my requirement, I need to send the escaped json as request to API service

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a= {
  "xx": "aa",
  "yy": "bb"
}

var nA = JSON.stringify(a, null, "\r\t");
var nB = JSON.stringify(nA);
console.log(nB)

document.getElementById("showData").value = JSON.parse(nB);
```

```html
<textarea id="showData" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
```

Comment: This is not the expected outcome. In addition, this code will break in so many situations, e.g. `{"foo":"{bar}"}`.

Comment: The same limitations still apply.

Comment: @str, First of all, JSON is valid coming from the request as OP mentioned. The second thing is: replace will find the first matched element. So no problem with the first statement. and second, replace will always check for the last element as I have used regex.

Comment: The OP's output contains whitespaces, yours does not.

Comment: @Hardik - Thanks for your code, please check my updated question, you can understand better of what I need.