# How to escape nested single quotes inside back tick or back quote

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals, backticks, backquote

Let's say we have the following template literal in ES6.

```
`'{"0": "It's Friday today"}'`
```

How do we escape the single quote in the word **It's**

Also, let's say we have the following template literal:

```
`'{"0": "Thursday\nFriday"}'`
```

How do we escape the `\n` in the above.

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253367/how-to-escape-a-json-string-containing-newline-characters-using-javascript/9204218

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It looks like stackoverflow didn't display the back tick at the starting and ending of the expressions I mentioned above.
I have edited the description.
FYI prefixing \ didn't work.

Comment: What is it you're doing that makes you want to define string literals within template literals?

Comment: I've updated my answer now that the question has been clarified.

Comment: Is that a string inside a JSON text in a single-quoted string literal inside a template string? To answer the question, we'd need to know on what level you want to do the escaping. Also, what generates these strings?

Comment: [Off-topic]: There's no JS version called ES16 (yet). There is ES2016 and ES6 (aka. ES2015)...

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to escape either of them, unless you want to use the contents of the template literal as a string literal quoted with a single quote at some point. Which looks really suspect: Never manually create JSON strings (and if you do, don't do it wrapped in a string literal in a template literal! :-) ). But if you're looking to define that string literal within the template literal here's how to do the escaping at the string literal level:

To escape the `'` in `It's` in the **string** literal the template will define, you need to put a backslash in front of it. But because backslashes are escapes in template literals, you need to escape the backslash so it's not consumed by the template literal and later is used when evaluating the string literal. So:

```js
// Define the template literal:
const s1 = `'{"0": "It\\'s Friday today"}'`;
// Escaped backslash −^^
console.log(s1);

// Evaluate the single-quoted string literal it defined:
const s2 = eval("(" + s1 + ")");
console.log(s2);

// Since that defined a string containing JSON, let's parse it:
const obj = JSON.parse(s2);
console.log(obj[0]);
```

In the second example with the `\n`, that `\n` escape sequence is being consumed at the template literal level, meaning the template literal contains a newline. But you want it not to be a newline from the template literal's perspective, so you...escape it: `\\n`. Now it's not a newline to the template literal anymore, but it is to the single-quoted string literal. Now it's the same as `It's` above: If you don't want the single-quoted string literal to consume the `\n` esape sequence, you need to escape it. That means you end up with `\\\\n`:

```js
// Define the template literal:
// 1st escaped backslash −−−vv
const s1 = `'{"0": "Thursday\\\\nFriday"}'`;
// 2nd escaped backslash −−−−−^^
console.log(s1);

// Evaluate the single-quoted string literal it defined:
const s2 = eval("(" + s1 + ")");
console.log(s2);

// Since that defined a string containing JSON, let's parse it:
const obj = JSON.parse(s2);
console.log(obj[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

1: Use a \ `'{"0": "It\'s Friday today"}'`
2: Again use \ `'{"0": "Thursday\\nFriday"}'`

Answer (score 0):

I think that using back ticks are wrong,
You can write that in this way:

```js
'\'{"0": "It\'s Friday today"}\''

'\'{"0": "Thursday\nFriday"}\''
```

Anyway i think the entire purpose of this is overcomplicated, if you just want to create a json, just create an object and then convert it to a json:

```js
var obj1 = {0: "It's Friday today"};
var obj2 = {0: "Thursday\nFriday"};

var json1 =  JSON.stringify(obj1);
var json2 =  JSON.stringify(obj2);

var final1 = "'" + json1 + "'";
var final2 = "'" + json2 + "'";
```

In this way is easier and it's less likely to syntax errors.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Apologies. It looks like stackoverflow didn't display the back tick at the starting and ending of the expressions I mentioned above.
I have edited the description.
FYI prefixing \ didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you don't have to escape them.

If you want to parse it later, you can use a template tag function.

Template tag functions receive an unescaped string to allow further processing.

The `String.raw` tag function, for example, returns a string without parsing additional escapes:

```js
console.log(String.raw `'{"0": "It\'s Friday today"}'`)
//       A single \ will do it ---^-----v
console.log(String.raw `'{"0": "Thursday\nFriday"}'`)
```