# How can I resolve JSON parsing error 'JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb

In NodeJS Backend, I send my data to client as:-

```
res.end(filex.replace("<userdata>", JSON.stringify({name:user.name, uid:user._id, profile:user.profile}) ))
```

//No error here and Object is stringified perfectly
//user is object returned in mongoDB's result
[image: MongoDB document]

The JSON string looks like this:

```
{"name":"Rishavolva","uid":"5f3ce234fd83024334050872","profile":{"pic":{"small_link":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyZXBsaWNhcyI6MiwidXJpcyI6W3siZGJfbmFtZSI6ImlmcmRiMDAxIiwidGFibGUiOiJGSUxFIiwiaWQiOjQ4fSx7ImRiX25hbWUiOiJpZnJkYjAwMiIsInRhYmxlIjoiRklMRSIsImlkIjo0OH1dLCJ1aWRfd2hpdGVsaXN0IjoiKiIsImlhdCI6MTU5ODE2MzMzNX0.9NkGnEumn4JW8IN0KFgxgN_6_4wN8qOgezNTyzz9osY","big_link":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyZXBsaWNhcyI6MiwidXJpcyI6W3siZGJfbmFtZSI6ImlmcmRiMDAxIiwidGFibGUiOiJGSUxFIiwiaWQiOjQ3fSx7ImRiX25hbWUiOiJpZnJkYjAwMiIsInRhYmxlIjoiRklMRSIsImlkIjo0N31dLCJ1aWRfd2hpdGVsaXN0IjoiKiIsImlhdCI6MTU5ODE2MzMzNX0.yxQ1GrhLsWPn8Qwu42EfTDXqaYwFtrM6f_7cAH2eLRY"},"aboutme":"I am Rishav Bhowmik\r\nand this is navratna pulaow"}}
```

and that UID is just a mongodb's primary key as string, and other two base 64 strings are just JWT tokens.

Now, when this JSON string reaches the Browser, I parse it with simple:

```
JSON.parse(`<userdata>`)
//remember I used filex.replace("<userdata>", JSON.stringify...) in the server
```

For reference, my MongoDB Document here is:

Now when JSON.parse is executed on the JSON string it will look like this on final JS code.

```
JSON.parse(`{"name":"Rishavolva","uid":"5f3ce234fd83024334050872","profile":{"pic":{"small_link":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyZXBsaWNhcyI6MiwidXJpcyI6W3siZGJfbmFtZSI6ImlmcmRiMDAxIiwidGFibGUiOiJGSUxFIiwiaWQiOjQ4fSx7ImRiX25hbWUiOiJpZnJkYjAwMiIsInRhYmxlIjoiRklMRSIsImlkIjo0OH1dLCJ1aWRfd2hpdGVsaXN0IjoiKiIsImlhdCI6MTU5ODE2MzMzNX0.9NkGnEumn4JW8IN0KFgxgN_6_4wN8qOgezNTyzz9osY","big_link":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyZXBsaWNhcyI6MiwidXJpcyI6W3siZGJfbmFtZSI6ImlmcmRiMDAxIiwidGFibGUiOiJGSUxFIiwiaWQiOjQ3fSx7ImRiX25hbWUiOiJpZnJkYjAwMiIsInRhYmxlIjoiRklMRSIsImlkIjo0N31dLCJ1aWRfd2hpdGVsaXN0IjoiKiIsImlhdCI6MTU5ODE2MzMzNX0.yxQ1GrhLsWPn8Qwu42EfTDXqaYwFtrM6f_7cAH2eLRY"},"aboutme":"I am Rishav Bhowmik\r\nand this is navratna pulaow"}}`)
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1 column 702 of the JSON data
```

the string at position 702 of the JSON string is `\n`

First of all, how can `\n` be a control character?

What should I do to resolve this?
Has this problem arrised due to MONGODB result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok have done some experimentation and have a solution.
The Trick is to do `JSON.stringify()` twice,

Like,

```
html_text.replace('/*<whatever>*/', JSON.stringify( JSON.stringify(the_object) ) )
```

If suppose html_text has a line which is

```
<script>
const object_inbrowser = JSON.parse(/*<whatever>*/)
// no need to add qotes, `JSON.stringify` in the server will do that for you
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is a control character signifying a new line. In JSON, those control characters (more specifically the `\`) must be escaped inside strings.

This will raise the error:

```
JSON.parse(`{"hello":"world\n"}`)
```

This wont:

```
   JSON.parse(`{"hello":"world\\n"}`)
```

So one way would be to use something like `replace` to ensure your `aboutme` is properly escaped before JSON serialization. See: [How to escape a JSON string containing newline characters using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253367/how-to-escape-a-json-string-containing-newline-characters-using-javascript)

Comment: Well then I guess I should use replace to embed the userdata directly with Object instead of parsing it on browser. I think that is the more appropriate was to do what I was doing.