# AutoFill Google Docs From Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm studding the solution proposed in this site:
https://jeffreyeverhart.com/2020/09/29/auto-fill-a-google-doc-template-from-google-sheet-data/
Especially I'm interesting in the replacement of tokens with data from a spreadsheet.

But I would like a more flexible solution. In this examples the tokens are defined in the code:

```
//In these lines, we replace our replacement tokens with values from our spreadsheet row
body.replaceText('{{First Name}}', row[0]);
body.replaceText('{{Last Name}}', row[1]);
body.replaceText('{{Position}}', row[2]);
```

I would like that all tokens available in the spreadsheet will replaced. For example as made in this solution applied for gmail templates:
https://developers.google.com/gsuite/solutions/mail-merge

```
 function fillInTemplateFromObject_(template, data) {
    // we have two templates one for plain text and the html body
    // stringifing the object means we can do a global replace
    let template_string = JSON.stringify(template);

    // token replacement
    template_string = template_string.replace(/{{[^{}]+}}/g, key => {
      return escapeData_(data[key.replace(/[{}]+/g, "")]) || "";
    });
    return  JSON.parse(template_string);
  };

  /**
   * Escape cell data to make JSON safe
   * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204218/1027723
   * @param {string} str to escape JSON special characters from
   * @return {string} escaped string
  */
  function escapeData_(str) {
    return str
      .replace(/[\\]/g, '\\\\')
      .replace(/[\"]/g, '\\\"')
      .replace(/[\/]/g, '\\/')
      .replace(/[\b]/g, '\\b')
      .replace(/[\f]/g, '\\f')
      .replace(/[\n]/g, '\\n')
      .replace(/[\r]/g, '\\r')
      .replace(/[\t]/g, '\\t');
  };
```

Thank you

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: basically i would like to replace all tokens in a google document with a function like template_string.replace(/{{[^{}]+}}/g, key => {
      return escapeData_(data[key.replace(/[{}]+/g, "")]) || ""; used in the second example

Comment: What is keeping your from doing it?

Comment: Because in google document I tried  .getBody().replace(/{{[^{}]+}}/g, key => { return escapeData_(data[key.replace(/[{}]+/g, "")]) || "";  and .getBody().replaceText(/{{[^{}]+}}/g, key => { return escapeData_(data[key.replace(/[{}]+/g, "")]) || "";  but don't work

Comment: Read the answer below I think that is your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replace()` you are trying to use in the document body is a Javascript method used for replacing string. Google Docs has [replaceText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement) method which you can use to replace string within the document without changing the document format.

If you want to use the `replace()`. You need to get the content of body (string) by using [method:getText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#gettext) and append the replace method.

**Example:**

[image: Example Docs]

Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var data = { 'name': 'John Doe', 'sport': 'Basketball', 'nba_player': 'Kobe Bryant'} 
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var text = body.getText();
  text = text.replace(/{{[^{}]+}}/g, key => {
      return escapeData_(data[key.replace(/[{}]+/g, "")] || "");
    });
  body.clear();
  body.setText(text);
}

function escapeData_(str) {
    return str
      .replace(/[\\]/g, '\\\\')
      .replace(/[\"]/g, '\\\"')
      .replace(/[\/]/g, '\\/')
      .replace(/[\b]/g, '\\b')
      .replace(/[\f]/g, '\\f')
      .replace(/[\n]/g, '\\n')
      .replace(/[\r]/g, '\\r')
      .replace(/[\t]/g, '\\t');
  };
```

**Output:**

[image]

Reference:

[Javascript String:replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Thanks. The solution work but the text loses its formatting. Is there the possibility to do the same thing using editAsText() and replaceText()?

Comment: @Michele - You can loop through the data and use replaceText() each iteration.