# How to update this JSON string with \" so it can be JSON.parse()?

Tags: javascript, json

So got this JSON string,

```
{
    "Text": "<?xml version=\"1.0\"</pi>",
    "Type": "Checkin"
}
```

I need to deserialize it back to an object.

```js
var returnedFileContent = '{"Text": "<?xml version=\"1.0\"</pi>","Type": "Checkin"}';
var test10 = JSON.parse(returnedFileContent);
console.log(test10)
```

Error:

> Unexpected number in JSON at position 25

I know JS doesn't like the \" and it will work if the JSON string is:

```
{
    "Text": "<?xml version=\\\\\\" 1.0\\\\\\ "</pi>",
    "Type": "Checkin"
}
```

**The problem is how to convert the \" to \\\".**

Note:  I have no control of the input JSON String.

Comment: Changing `\"` to `\'` seems to work, but if it does not parse, it is not JSON.

Comment: Also, is the Text _actually_ `"<?xml version=\"1.0\"</pi>"` ? That's not valid XML, either.

Comment: And sometimes, the right answer is to have some other person or team fix their stuff.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape a JSON string containing newline characters using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253367/how-to-escape-a-json-string-containing-newline-characters-using-javascript)

Comment: msanford, it is not valid XML.  You are right!  I am just simplified the string to make a case here.  
crashmstr, this JSON string actually can be parsed and is valid in C#.  And this JSON is generated from one of our C# library.  
@Balastrong, yes, the top answer in that post looks like a good workaround.  I will give it a try.  

Thank you for all the suggestions!