# How to appropriately handle newlines and the escaping of them?

Tags: text, escaping, newline

I'm integrating output from OpenAI's ChatGPT streaming API into a web application and facing challenges with rendering newline characters `\n` as well as dealing with `\\n` (which represents an escaped newline character). The output can contain newlines that need to be displayed as HTML line breaks (`<br />`) in most text. However, there are specific scenarios, such as within code blocks or when \n or \n are part of the instructional content, where these newline indicators should be preserved as-is.

The simple naive approach of globally replacing `\n` with `<br />` does not suffice, as it fails to distinguish between contexts where a newline is meant for formatting versus when it is part of the actual content (e.g., `\n` appearing in a string within a programming tutorial or `\\n` used to demonstrate escape sequences in text).

I find it a bit funny I've programmed for so many years and I've likely run into this problem in various forms, and it seems to have always been handled very automatically by whatever escaping mechanisms, yet when I think of the problem it seems a lot more complicated.

Is there some kind of text formatting standard or convention for how this should be handled? Or perhaps this something like this little search replace is all I really need and it's capable of handling all cases?

```
var myEscapedJSONString = myJSONString.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n")
                                      .replace(/\\'/g, "\\'")
                                      .replace(/\\"/g, '\\"')
                                      .replace(/\\&/g, "\\&")
                                      .replace(/\\r/g, "\\r")
                                      .replace(/\\t/g, "\\t")
                                      .replace(/\\b/g, "\\b")
                                      .replace(/\\f/g, "\\f");
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4253415/1663462

Answer (score -1):

Handling newlines and escape sequences in web app text is like managing a mixed bag of goodies. You've got your regular text, code bits, and instructions, each needing different treatment. Think of it like sorting your laundry – regular clothes go in the washer, delicate stuff gets hand-washed, and funky fabrics need special care. So, for text, slap those 
 tags on newlines but keep the \n's intact in code blocks. And don't forget to watch out for XSS gremlins by HTML-encoding special characters!