# json_encode won't escape newlines

Tags: php, javascript, yii, json

Firstly, I have search Stack Overflow for the answer, but I have not found a solution that works.

I am using an MVC framework (yii) to generate some views and throw them in an array. Each view is a card, and I have an array of cards ($deck) as well as an array of arrays of cards ($hands, the list of hands for each player). I'm simply trying to set a javascript variable on the front-end to store the hands created in PHP. My view has, it is worth noting, multiple lines. In fact, my current test view consists only of:

```
test
test
```

I therefore used json_encode, but it's giving me the following error when I use $.parseJSON():

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token t
```

I read elsewhere that it is required (for whatever reason) to use json_encode twice. I have tried this, but it does not help.

With a single json_encode, the output of echoing `$hands` (followed by an exit) looks pretty healthy:

```
[["test\ntest","test\ntest","test\ntest","test\ntest", etc...
```

But when I do not exit, I get a syntax error every time.

Edit: Here is a sample of my code. Note that $cards is an array of HTML normally, but in my simplified case which still errors, includes only the two lines of 'test' as mentioned above.

```
    $deck = array();
    foreach ($cards as $card) {
        $deck[] = $this->renderPartial('/gamePieces/cardTest', 
                array('card'=>$card), true);
    }
    $hands = Cards::handOutCards($deck, $numCards , $numPlayers);
    $hands = json_encode($hands);

    echo $hands; exit;
```

With JavaScript, I am doing the following:

```
var hands = $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($hands); ?>');
```

It errors on page load.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

ParagonRG

Comment: Using json_encode twice makes very little sense.

Comment: Then why don't you keep the exit? And why is there an extraneous `"` quote before the JSON array brackets?

Comment: Please show some of your actual code, including the part that uses `json_encode`.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question to display more code. Obviously I can't keep the exit, as my view will not render. As for the extra quotation mark, I do not know why it was there; I echoed and it was not there, so I edited my question.

Comment: @pointy I agree, but I found it the following SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048487/phps-json-encode-does-not-escape-all-json-control-characters .

Comment: @Paragon that question is nonsense; the poster there was quite confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var hands = $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($hands); ?>');
```

This will result in something like:

```
var hands = $.parseJSON('{"foobar":"baz'"}');
```

If there are `'` characters in the encoded string, it'll break the Javascript syntax. Since you're directly outputting the JSON into Javacript, just do:

```
var hands = <?php echo json_encode($hands); ?>;
```

JSON is syntactically valid Javascript. You only need to parse it or `eval` it if you receive it as a string through AJAX for instance. If you're directly generating Javascript source code, just embed it directly.

Comment: Thank you. This was a fundamental issue that I was not getting; problem solved.