# Alternative to JSON when line breaks are needed?

Tags: php, xml, json

I made a rudimentary label-printing web app using PHP, and I need a way to store the templates. These consist of a few small text entries and some number and boolean values. Normally I would just use JSON but the text values contain line breaks which JSON can't handle. XML is a pain because there is HTML markup I would have to escape. Is there another alternative format I could use to store this information which is human-readable?

Comment: you should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253367/how-to-escape-a-json-string-containing-newline-characters-using-javascript

Comment: I think he wants to encode in PHP and then send to the client if I am reading correctly.  The referenced article describes how to encode a string for JSON in Javascript.

Comment: I'm actually just trying to save the file on the server and then retrieve it later. Nothing is being sent to the client for Javascript.

Comment: It's not true that JSON can't handle line breaks. You just need to escape them as `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to prep the data and encode it into JSON on the server then send it to the client.   [This article](http://www.pontikis.net/tip/?id=5) gives a good explanation on how to prep your data escaping the proper values for evaluation on the client.

Newer versions of PHP (> 5.2) have the json_encode() function which will perform this task:

```
$str_valid=json_encode($str);
```

There are many options for this function, read [the docs](http://php.net/json_encode) for more info.

Older versions of PHP need to provide this functionality:

```
/**
 * @param $value
 * @return mixed
 */
function escapeJsonString($value) { # list from www.json.org: (\b backspace, \f formfeed)
    $escapers = array("\\", "/", "\"", "\n", "\r", "\t", "\x08", "\x0c");
    $replacements = array("\\\\", "\\/", "\\\"", "\\n", "\\r", "\\t", "\\f", "\\b");
    $result = str_replace($escapers, $replacements, $value);
    return $result;
}
```

Interestingly,  the article references back to this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048487/phps-json-encode-does-not-escape-all-json-control-characters) where the same function appears.

Comment: Don't try to manipulate strings as if they are json.  You can, but it's more trouble than it's worth.  Create the object with keys and values, then call json_encode on the object itself to get the json string.  The json plugin guys have already done all the work for you, plus they keep it maintained.