# How to output JSON parse compatible json with PHP json_encode? JSON.parse - Unexpected token h due to single escaped double quotes

Tags: javascript, php, json, encode

I have this php:

```
<?php

    $jsonarr = array("haha" => array("hihi'hih","hu\"huh"));
    print json_encode($jsonarr);
```

This gives me

```
{"haha":["hihi'hih","hu\"huh"]}
```

Now, in JSON.parse this breaks with

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token h
    at Object.parse (native)
```

, unless I double escape the backslash like this

```
var json = '{"haha":{"hihi\'hih":"hu\\\"huh"}}';
JSON.parse(json);
```

How can I get php to create a JSON parse compatible output?

Meanwhile, I did get this to work with double json_encoding the string in php based on this [PHP's json_encode does not escape all JSON control characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048487/phps-json-encode-does-not-escape-all-json-control-characters) like this, but wonder if there is some other way.

```
$jsonarr = array("haha" => array("hihi'hih","hu\"huh"));
        print json_encode(json_encode($jsonarr));
```

Comment: Are you getting this from AJAX, or embedding in the page? (I believe embedding in the page; if so, don't `JSON.parse`. You're breaking it, not `json_encode`.)

Comment: I am accessing a php json_encoded file on my server from a Google Apps script, and there I can fetch that file as a string. So, I must do a JSON parse to get it into an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were getting this from AJAX, it wouldn't be happening, so I believe you're generating JS code using PHP, something like this:

```
var json = '<?php echo $jsonarr; ?>';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

This won't work, because, as you noted, `$jsonarr` when printed will not have the requisite number of backslashes. `\"` in JSON needs to be `\\"` in a JS string literal in order to be understood as `\"`.

Instead, remember that JSON is executable JS:

```
var obj = <?php echo $jsonarr; ?>;
```

Done!

Comment: I am accessing  a php json_encoded file on my server from a Google Apps script, and there I can fetch that file as a string. So, I must do a JSON parse to get it into an object.

Comment: If you have a JSON string in PHP, you can just print it as JS *code* into your page, no `JSON.parse` needed, as long as you're letting PHP generate your page for you.