# Escape JSON character in PHP

Tags: php, json

I create json string with out array by using user input 
But some time error can be occur user input some JSON character
such as , " { [ ..etc

I should want to escape all character and i sholud want to show user input data without any change

ex. "I'm "   i should want show this input without change

Comment: See the answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3615890/204842

Answer (score -1):

you need to escape your characters:

```
$pattern = '/([{|}|\[|\]|\'|\"])/gi';
$replacement = '\${1}';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. The 'g' at the end of the pattern causes preg_replace to return nothing, and it's not actually needed because preg_replace already replaces all occurrences of the pattern. Also, the replacement should be '\\\\${1}', which inserts a single backslash in front of the character found in the pattern.

A better answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3615890/204842