# Php escape special characters in a JSON string

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array of product details, in the **product_description** string I want to escape some special characters such as: " , \ ..etc but I don't know what should I write exactly to do so, what I did was:

```
json_encode($array[ProductData][Product_description]);
```

but then when I checked the result, it gives me errors regarding those special characters.

Here's the product description string:

> The 30" Apple Cinema HD Display deliver..etc

The error is in the double-quote.

Can you please assist me on how to do it. Thank you

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the product description is, and maybe the exact error it is giving? That will help in finding out what is wrong.

Comment: @BrianLogan I have edited the question again, please check and assist me if possible. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can try with

```
    $value = json_encode($array[ProductData][Product_description]);
    $escapers = array("\\", "/", "\"", "\n", "\r", "\t", "\x08", "\x0c");
    $replacements = array("\\\\", "\\/", "\\\"", "\\n", "\\r", "\\t", "\\f", "\\b");
    $result = str_replace($escapers, $replacements, $value);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '<pre>';
```

---

This is the reference

[PHP's json_encode does not escape all JSON control characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048487/phps-json-encode-does-not-escape-all-json-control-characters)

Comment: I have tried it but the result will be affect even the double quotes of JSON itself: instead of **"The 30\" Apple Cinema HD Display deliver..etc"** it gives me this result: **\"The 30\" Apple Cinema HD Display deliver..etc\"**

Answer (score 3):

The error you are facing is because the `"` is not escaped in the array. It most likely looks like the following:

```
$array = array(
    "ProductData" => array(
        "ProductName": "Apple Cinema Display",
        "ProductDescription" => "The 30" Apple Cinema HD Display deliver..etc"
    )
);
```

To fix the issue, in your code you should make it the following:

```
$array = array(
    "ProductData" => array(
        "ProductName": "Apple Cinema Display",
        "ProductDescription" => "The 30\" Apple Cinema HD Display deliver..etc"
    )
);
```

If you are pulling from a database, this should be done automatically. My suggestion, if you are not using a database, is to manually add the backslashes in where needed. There won't be a reliable function to automatically add them since you are most likely using double quotes around the whole string.

Comment: I have tried the str_replace suggested in the other answer, but it's not really working for me; you are right, I am not pulling the data from the database. so by manually adding the backslashes where needed, you mean it like literally add it. because I have so many products that most of them have special characters. this won't be an efficient way to do it.

Comment: The best and easiest way to do it would be to make a quick database using MySQL (it is free and open source) and inserting the data into it. It will also allow you to clean up your code a substantial amount.