# JSON decode (objects in object)

Tags: php, json

How to decode this string into normal PHP Array?

```
$json ='{
    "rezultatas": "[\r\n    {\r\n        \"laikas\": \"2017-06-15 09:40:00\",\r\n        \"komentaras\": \"pirminė konsultacija sergantiems diabetu (turėti gliukomatį ir dienyną)\\t\",\r\n        \"savaitesDiena\": 5,\r\n        \"id\": 47293965,\r\n        \"kabinetas\": \"147\",\r\n        \"istPavadinimas\": \"Lietuvos sveikatos mokslų universiteto ligoninė Kauno klinikos\",\r\n        \"specialybe\": \"ENDOKRINOLOGAS\",\r\n        \"gydytojas\": \"STASIŪNAS TADAS\",\r\n        \"pareigybe\": \"GYDYTOJAS ENDOKRINOLOGAS\",\r\n        \"kabPav\": \"Endokrinologijos ambulatorija\",\r\n        \"redaguoja\": 0\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n        \"laikas\": \"2017-06-22 09:20:00\",\r\n        \"komentaras\": \"pirminė konsultacija,sergantiems diabetu (turėti gliukomatį ir dienyną)\",\r\n        \"savaitesDiena\": 5,\r\n        \"id\": 47293968,\r\n        \"kabinetas\": \"147\",\r\n        \"istPavadinimas\": \"Lietuvos sveikatos mokslų universiteto ligoninė Kauno klinikos\",\r\n        \"specialybe\": \"ENDOKRINOLOGAS\",\r\n        \"gydytojas\": \"STASIŪNAS TADAS\",\r\n        \"pareigybe\": \"GYDYTOJAS ENDOKRINOLOGAS\",\r\n        \"kabPav\": \"Endokrinologijos ambulatorija\",\r\n        \"redaguoja\": 0\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n        \"laikas\": \"2017-06-22 09:40:00\",\r\n        \"komentaras\": \"pirminė konsultacija sergantiems diabetu (turėti gliukomatį ir dienyną)\\t\",\r\n        \"savaitesDiena\": 5,\r\n        \"id\": 47293969,\r\n        \"kabinetas\": \"147\",\r\n        \"istPavadinimas\": \"Lietuvos sveikatos mokslų universiteto ligoninė Kauno klinikos\",\r\n        \"specialybe\": \"ENDOKRINOLOGAS\",\r\n        \"gydytojas\": \"STASIŪNAS TADAS\",\r\n        \"pareigybe\": \"GYDYTOJAS ENDOKRINOLOGAS\",\r\n        \"kabPav\": \"Endokrinologijos ambulatorija\",\r\n        \"redaguoja\": 0\r\n    }\r\n]",
    "klaida": null
}';

$result = json_decode($json, true);

print_r($result['rezultatas']);
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the `\\t` sequence in your inner JSON (appears twice).

Comment: where does `$json['rezultatas']` come from?

Comment: I think @Tom is right, it's a parsing issue. Fwiw, json_decode() isn't perfect... Maybe something like this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048487/phps-json-encode-does-not-escape-all-json-control-characters#3615890

Comment: I fetch it from website with file gets content. I want convert it to standart array and do another action with php.

Comment: Now works for sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1) You decode the outer part of your JSON string but the inner part (`rezultatas`) also needs to be decoded.
2) It appears that the tab escape, `\t`, causes some problems while decoding your JSON.

You should strip the `\t` sequence in your JSON string before decoding:

```
<?php
$json ='{
    "rezultatas": "[\r\n    {\r\n        \"laikas\": \"2017-06-15 09:40:00\",\r\n        \"komentaras\": \"pirminė konsultacija sergantiems diabetu (turėti gliukomatį ir dienyną)\\t\",\r\n        \"savaitesDiena\": 5,\r\n        \"id\": 47293965,\r\n        \"kabinetas\": \"147\",\r\n        \"istPavadinimas\": \"Lietuvos sveikatos mokslų universiteto ligoninė Kauno klinikos\",\r\n        \"specialybe\": \"ENDOKRINOLOGAS\",\r\n        \"gydytojas\": \"STASIŪNAS TADAS\",\r\n        \"pareigybe\": \"GYDYTOJAS ENDOKRINOLOGAS\",\r\n        \"kabPav\": \"Endokrinologijos ambulatorija\",\r\n        \"redaguoja\": 0\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n        \"laikas\": \"2017-06-22 09:20:00\",\r\n        \"komentaras\": \"pirminė konsultacija,sergantiems diabetu (turėti gliukomatį ir dienyną)\",\r\n        \"savaitesDiena\": 5,\r\n        \"id\": 47293968,\r\n        \"kabinetas\": \"147\",\r\n        \"istPavadinimas\": \"Lietuvos sveikatos mokslų universiteto ligoninė Kauno klinikos\",\r\n        \"specialybe\": \"ENDOKRINOLOGAS\",\r\n        \"gydytojas\": \"STASIŪNAS TADAS\",\r\n        \"pareigybe\": \"GYDYTOJAS ENDOKRINOLOGAS\",\r\n        \"kabPav\": \"Endokrinologijos ambulatorija\",\r\n        \"redaguoja\": 0\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n        \"laikas\": \"2017-06-22 09:40:00\",\r\n        \"komentaras\": \"pirminė konsultacija sergantiems diabetu (turėti gliukomatį ir dienyną)\\t\",\r\n        \"savaitesDiena\": 5,\r\n        \"id\": 47293969,\r\n        \"kabinetas\": \"147\",\r\n        \"istPavadinimas\": \"Lietuvos sveikatos mokslų universiteto ligoninė Kauno klinikos\",\r\n        \"specialybe\": \"ENDOKRINOLOGAS\",\r\n        \"gydytojas\": \"STASIŪNAS TADAS\",\r\n        \"pareigybe\": \"GYDYTOJAS ENDOKRINOLOGAS\",\r\n        \"kabPav\": \"Endokrinologijos ambulatorija\",\r\n        \"redaguoja\": 0\r\n    }\r\n]",
    "klaida": null
}';

$json = str_replace('\t', '', $json); // strip '\t' from your JSON
$result = json_decode($json, true); // decode outer part

print_r(json_decode($result['rezultatas'],true)); // decode inner part
?>
```

which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [laikas] => 2017-06-15 09:40:00
            [komentaras] => pirminė konsultacija sergantiems diabetu (turėti gliukomatį ir dienyną)
            [savaitesDiena] => 5
            [id] => 47293965
            [kabinetas] => 147
            [istPavadinimas] => Lietuvos sveikatos mokslų universiteto ligoninė Kauno klinikos
            [specialybe] => ENDOKRINOLOGAS
            [gydytojas] => STASIŪNAS TADAS
            [pareigybe] => GYDYTOJAS ENDOKRINOLOGAS
            [kabPav] => Endokrinologijos ambulatorija
            [redaguoja] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [laikas] => 2017-06-22 09:20:00
            [komentaras] => pirminė konsultacija,sergantiems diabetu (turėti gliukomatį ir dienyną)
            [savaitesDiena] => 5
            [id] => 47293968
            [kabinetas] => 147
            [istPavadinimas] => Lietuvos sveikatos mokslų universiteto ligoninė Kauno klinikos
            [specialybe] => ENDOKRINOLOGAS
            [gydytojas] => STASIŪNAS TADAS
            [pareigybe] => GYDYTOJAS ENDOKRINOLOGAS
            [kabPav] => Endokrinologijos ambulatorija
            [redaguoja] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [laikas] => 2017-06-22 09:40:00
            [komentaras] => pirminė konsultacija sergantiems diabetu (turėti gliukomatį ir dienyną)
            [savaitesDiena] => 5
            [id] => 47293969
            [kabinetas] => 147
            [istPavadinimas] => Lietuvos sveikatos mokslų universiteto ligoninė Kauno klinikos
            [specialybe] => ENDOKRINOLOGAS
            [gydytojas] => STASIŪNAS TADAS
            [pareigybe] => GYDYTOJAS ENDOKRINOLOGAS
            [kabPav] => Endokrinologijos ambulatorija
            [redaguoja] => 0
        )

)
```

Check for https://3v4l.org/kja5S the output.