# PHP: regex in JSON causes problem for json_decode?

Tags: php, json, regex, escaping

I have some regular expressions in my JSON, which doesn't seem to be a problem when I test my JSON on an online JSON validator. However, when I take that JSON string and try to `json_decode()` in PHP, I get a **JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX**.

Any ideas why? And how do I solve this?

**Sample code:**

```
<?php

$json = <<<EOD
{
  "regex": [
    "Hello\s+World"
  ]
}
EOD;

json_decode($json);

switch (json_last_error()) {
    case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
        echo ' - No errors';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
        echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
        echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
        echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
        echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
        echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
    break;
    default:
        echo ' - Unknown error';
    break;
}
```

The problem is in the `\s`. Changing it to `\\s` doesn't help.

Comment: Which online JSON validator validates the one in this question?

Comment: Take a look at [this package](https://github.com/MAChitgarha/JSON). You can easily convert an array to a JSON string using it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you write `"\s"` in PHP the literal string is `\s` because `\s` is not a valid escape sequence.

When you write `"\\s"` in PHP the literal string is `\s` because `\\` *is* a valid escape sequence.

JSON, on the other hand will throw an error for invalid escape sequences, which is your issue.

**The solution:** *Don't write JSON by hand.*

```
$json = json_encode(['regex'=> ['Hello\s+World']]);
```

Output: `{"regex":["Hello\\s+World"]}` [note: literal string, valid JSON]

**The Bad Solution That's More Trouble than it's Worth and Will Probably Cause Problems Down the Line:** `"Hello\\\s+World"` welcome to escaping hell.

Comment: When I json_decode as JSON array, I expect a PHP array in return. I'm getting a string. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Your array probably has been encoded several times. Show your starting JSON.

Answer (score 3):

Your string `"Hello\s+World"` must be escaped like `"Hello\\\s+World"`. The first escape `\` is for escape the second escape `\` which escape `\s`.

And then if you want to have an array in output then you have to set `assoc = true` as second parameter for `json_decode()` function.

Read more about `json_decode()` function in **[documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)**.

**Solution**

See the **[DEMO](https://www.ideone.com/FIMTEm)** from my code.

```
<?php
$json = '{"regex":["Hello\\\s+World"]}';

$obj1 = json_decode($json);
echo $obj1->regex[0]."<br>";

$obj2 = json_decode($json, true); //When assoc == TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.
echo $obj2["regex"][0];
?>
```

How to escape all JSON control characters:

- **[PHP's json_encode does not escape all JSON control characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615890/9801830)**

Answer (score 1):

Because of potentially complex regex and double escaping problem, you're not getting the string literal you are expecting.

This should work for any regex:

```
$regex1 = <<<EOD
Hello\s+World
EOD;

$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->regex = array();
$obj->regex[] = $regex1;

$json = json_encode($obj);

$decoded = json_decode($json);

var_dump($decoded->regex[0]);
```

**output**:

```
string(13) "Hello\s+World"
```